# Starting point of a circular linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I was looking at the circular linked list (completely new to data structures) and got confused on what the starting point of circular linked list would be?

Answer (score 0):

Any of the nodes in the list can be used as the starting point because the list is circular and any node can be reached (eventually) from any other.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you.